# Icinga2 : Hosts in downtime

Tags: linux, icinga2

How to find a host in downtime in icinga2 using api or from mysql database. I have tried using below api, but its not displaying there.

```
curl -H 'Cache-Control: no-cache' -k  -u root:icinga 'https://localhost:5665/v1/objects/hosts?host=hostanme.com'
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm using `downtime_depth` attribute, although I'm not 100% sure about it.

```
curl -k -s
    'https://localhost:5665/v1/objects/hosts?filter=host.downtime_depth!=0' | \
python -mjson.tool`
```